# Delphi7, Zeos DB et Postgres

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, delphi-7, zeos

I'm working on an application in Delphi using PostgreSQL as a database. I'm actually getting a problem with the connection in design-time: when I try to run a simple query like :

```
select * from article;
```

I get a message which says that the table `article` *does not exist* whereas it does exist, besides when I execute the program, the query runs correctly.

I note that the **TZConnection** connects well to the Postgres database at design time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check that you are connected to the right database. Make sure your search_path is set to the right schema or otherwise use a fully qualified tablename.

Comment: I'm really connected to the db, in fact I can run a query to a specific table but not to the others. I also tried with `public.tableName` but no response.

Comment: What do you see when you connect with psql and execute `\dt`?

Comment: All tables are shown

Comment: what does `\dp article` show?

Comment: compare it with `\dp some_other_table` where your queries are successful.

Comment: It does show all the data from the `article` table, event with the other tables but when I use the `zeos` to query the database it tells me that this one does not exist with error 104. It's very confusing because I tried with `public` schema even though it does not work.

Comment: If you see the same permissions for both tables in psql, debug your client side: You can set `log_statement = 'all' ` and `log_min_error_statement = 'ERROR'` in postgresql.conf. So you can see what is actually sent to the database.